# Filter raster data by year

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, filter

I need exclude a number of years from a deforestation raster layer. I have 2000-2019 deforestation data and I only require 2011-2015 data for my project. I have tried using raster calculator, but each time I either get an error or end up with the wrong years.

Does anyone know the code that I would need to filter this raster layer?

I was hoping that definition queries would work but that is only for vector data - unless I can vectorise - define data - rasterise and the filter would remain.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro and the raster layer is a tif format of global forest Loss_Year from the global forest watch (Hansen) with tiles merged into one layer.

Comment: Can you split the years into individual rasters, rather than bands in one large multi-band raster? You could then rejoin the 5 years if needed to form a new smaller multi-band raster. For exact instructions it would be helpful if you could edit your questions to provide details about the software you are using and file type for your raster.

Comment: Which software are you working with? Which data are you working with? What have you tried (include expressions in text form)?

Comment: @ycartwhelen I've just updated my question. But the data come from global forest watch and it's the forest loss data (TIF). It downloads as tiles by geographic location but come as one large multi band raster. I'm relatively new to GIS so some of the terminology confuses me still - i.e its raster to polygon for ArcPro not Vectorise as a mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing a multi-band raster where each band is a years worth of data? Think of it as a stack of raster layers, each layer a year of data all in one dataset (tif).

You can use the [Make Raster Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/make-raster-layer.htm) to extract out individual bands, simply set the band parameter. If you need to make the layer permanent then export the raster layer.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. I’ve realised the data is a single band raster rather than multi-band, but you’re able to select the value expressions in Make Raster layer so it’s done the job - thank you!